# Affinity Propagation with missing data

Tags: clustering, missing-data

I'm using Affinity Propagation to cluster some data, and I have to deal with missing values, so for points that I have the data, I can use it to change similarity between them, but for those that I don't have, I don't reflect it in their similarity.
The problem is that Affinity Propagation chooses a point as exemplar of a cluster, and it chooses other members of that cluster through their similarity to this exemplar. So in my case, it happens that it chooses a point as exemplar that misses some value, and in the cluster that it forms around this exemplar it puts some points that don't miss any value, but are not similar to each other in regard to that missing value. The problem stems from the point that I can't reflect missing values in similarities.
Is there any way to deal better with missing values when using affinity propagation?

Comment: How about data imputation, auch as using the mode for missing values?